# Turn multi-index of pandas series into dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Series with a multi-index:

```
import pandas as pd
index = pd.MultiIndex(labels = [[0,1,1],[2,2,3]], levels = [[1,2],[1,2,3,4]], names = ['a','b'])
s = pd.Series(index=index, data=[100,200,300])

a  b
1  3    100
2  3    200
   4    300
```

I want to transform it into a DataFrame where the rows are the labels of the first index (e.g. a), the columns are the labels of the second index (e.g. b), and the values the values at index (a,b) (or None if there is none):

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index(data=[1,2],name='a'), 
                          data = [[100,None],[200,300]],
                         columns = [3,4])


    3   4
a       
1   100 NaN
2   200 300.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) function:

```
print (s.unstack())
b      3      4
a              
1  100.0    NaN
2  200.0  300.0
```